# how to plot lines matching data using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

plot increase_rate contains `abs(increase_rate) > 0.05`.
but under the code, discard the data between -0.05 to 0.05.

I also plot data including from -0.05 to 0.05 range.

```
library(tidyverse)
data(population, package="tidyr")

population %>%
  arrange(country, year) %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  mutate(population_nextY = lead(population)) %>%
  mutate(increase_rate = (population_nextY - population)/population_nextY) %>%
  filter(abs(increase_rate) > 0.05) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  ggplot()+
  geom_line(aes(x = year, y = increase_rate, color = country))
```

I want to get final plot like this.[image]

```
d <- 
  population %>%
  arrange(country, year) %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  mutate(population_nextY = lead(population)) %>%
  mutate(increase_rate = (population_nextY - population)/population_nextY) %>%
  ungroup

select_country <- 
  d %>% filter(!between(increase_rate, -0.05, 0.05)) %>%
  select(country) %>% distinct %>% unlist

d %>%
  filter(country %in% select_country) %>%
  ggplot()+
  geom_line(aes(x = year, y = increase_rate, color = country))
```

Answer (score 0):

use `between`:

```
filter(!between(increase_rate, -0.05, 0.05))
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you were trying to exclude data between -0.05 and 0.05 or limit to that. If the latter, remove the `!`

Comment: It's mean, Plot for countries having abs(increse_rate)>0.05.

Comment: cool, then the above should work. Let me know if you run into anything

Comment: Sorry,I added the details I am asking for the question.

Answer (score 0):

add column using mutate() function

```
population %>%
  arrange(country, year) %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  mutate(population_nextY = lead(population)) %>%
  mutate(increase_rate = (population_nextY - population)/population_nextY) %>%
  mutate(judge = max(abs(increase_rate), na.rm=T)) %>%
  filter(judge > 0.05) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_line(aes(x = year, y = increase_rate, color = country))
```